# Routing with Node & Express on Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-appservice

I'm not sure if this is a Node question or an Azure App Service question, but here goes:

I have a Node/Express app with two routes:

```
router.get("/users", checkAuthHeader, userController.getUsers);
router.post("/users", checkAuthHeader, userController.createUser);
```

On my local, this runs exactly as expected. `GET /users` returns a list of users, while `POST /users` creates a new user from the request body.

However, when I deploy this to Azure (vanilla setup of Azure App Service), any request to `/users` hits the request handler for `GET /users`, regardless of request method.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Can you check once the **createUser** & **getUser** controller whether those contain the same lines of code?. You can check these in azure using the KUDU console/ App Service Editor. If it's not the same lines of code. Share your controller code to check further.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a basic `nodejs` web app in azure .
Here in my case I didn't overcome your problem of **Post** request not being able to reach .

#### POST Response :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dJJmNcb.png]

#### GET Response :

[image]

Check the line of codes/response of your controller methods of **GET** & **POST** in KUDU/App Service Editor.